# Debian 10 fcitx not starting on startup

Tags: debian, d-bus, fcitx

I was trying to add another language on debian 10 with KDE and I got this
[image]

I searched the net and found one solution, if I run

```
dbus-launch fcitx
```

I can use the `Input Method`tab. To make this start on boot, I found that I need to add

```
exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch --exit-with-session openbox
```

in my `~/.xinitrc`file. In my home directory I didn't have one, so I made one like below

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch --exit-with-session openbox
```

And then I rebooted. But it doesn't work. Now I'm lost, what should I do?
solution source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/fcitx-cannot-launch-current-4175418957/